# im trying to print out an incrementing function in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to increment form and let the loop break out when it reaches 10.
Keep getting stuck in an infinite loop and I don't know why?

```
x = 0
form = x
while True:
    if form == 10:
        break
    else:
        x += 1
```

Comment: I have added in your code, and removed the link to the picture. Welcome to SO. Next time do put in the code so everyone can see this.

Answer (score 0):

Your exit of the `while` loop is when `form == 10`, however `form = x` is outside the loop, so `form` will always have the value of `0`, and will not get updated.

You need to put the `form = x` inside the `while` loop, something like this:

```
x = 0
while True:
    form = x
    if form == 10:
        break
    else:
        x += 1
```

Unless you do something else with `form`, you can actually just use `x`, something like this:

```
x = 0
while True:
    if x == 10:
        break
    else:
        x += 1
```